# How to get data from a .DBF file in iPhone

Tags: iphone, database

I need to get data from my database which is a .dbf file. Is it possible to fetch data from the same to the iPhone. How is it done? Please help needed.

Comment: are you talking about .db file

Comment: [check the below Link it's very usefull to you:](https://github.com/davbeck/DBF-Reader)

Answer (score 1):

I forked https://github.com/davbeck/DBF-Reader/ at https://github.com/woodnathan/DBF-Reader/ to make an iPhone compatible wrapper

There's a little bit of work to do, and I'll be continuing to update over the next few days/weeks to improve it, hopefully it will help you out in its current state

Comment: did u make it compatible for iphone?

Comment: Yep, only requires ARC which can be enabled per file using -fobjc-arc